# How to ignore click events on Slivers of CustomScrollView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, flutter-ignore-pointer

I have a `Stack` widget as the body of the `Scaffold` and the stack has a `CustomScrollView` and some other widget behind the scroll view as its children.

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      WidgetBehindTheScrollView(),
      CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(),
          SliverBelowTheAppBar(),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

What I want to achieve is to make `WidgetBehindTheScrollView` clickable by making `SliverBelowTheAppBar` ignore the pointer events on occasion. But I don't want `SliverAppBar` to ignore pointer events. So I can't wrap the `CustomScrollView` with [`IgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html).

I tried wrapping `SliverBelowTheAppBar` with [`SliverIgnorePointer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverIgnorePointer-class.html) but I still can't interact with the `WidgetBehindTheScrollView`.

Comment: why would you want this behaviour? the scrollview is on the top to receive touch event for scrolling, if the underneath view is also clickable, the system will be confused if you want to scroll or click.

Comment: It's a little complicated, I have a search bar at the bottom of the AppBar and when I click the search bar, I want to display search results where the SliverBelowTheAppBar located. But I don't want the search results to be inside the ScrollView (to be a Sliver). So I placed it under the ScrollView using a Stack.

Comment: why not placing the search results above the scrollview?

Comment: That's exactly what I tried first. But the AppBar has a shadow underneath and if I place the results above the ScrollView, then the shadow stays behind the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combo widget Sliver:

```
     // ),
            SliverIgnorePointer(
              ignoring: true,
              ignoringSemantics: true,
              sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: IgnorePointer(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    height: kSpaceBottom,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```